# show more jerking - jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table of contents which is shown with 3 rows by default and on clicking more it shows all the rows. But the there is a jerk.

[here is the link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vickysk/v2Sht/) I need some smooth effect so i use slideUp and slideDown instead of show or hide. show or hide is working fine.

I tried setting height of table in script but it did not help. Any help on this jerk..

```
var numShown = 3; // Initial rows shown & index
    var $table = $('table').find('tbody');  // tbody containing all the rows
    var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows

    $(function () {

        // Hide rows and add clickable div
        if (numRows > numShown){
            $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end();
            $('#more-less a').show();
            $('#more-less a').click(function() {
                $('table').css('height',$(this).height);
                if (numRows > numShown){
                    numShown = numRows;
                    $('#more-less a').html("Show less");
                    $('#more-less a').attr('class','less');
                    $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').slideDown();
                }
                else{
                    numShown = 3;
                    $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').slideUp().end();
                    $('#more-less a').html("Show more");
                    $('#more-less a').attr('class','more');

                }
            });
        }
        else{
            $('#more-less a').hide()
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it in a different way and got rid of the jerk.

Wrapped the table in a div and used animate() to animate height.
Here is the working[Fiddle for your reference](http://jsfiddle.net/vickysk/3hYuf/)

```
var $table=$('.tableContainer');
var aH=$('table').css('height');
var h=0;
var numOfRows=3;
$('table tr').each(function(indx, obj){
    if(indx<numOfRows){

    h+=$(obj).height();
    }



});
var heightToHide=h+5;       
$table.css('height',heightToHide);
$('.more').click(function(){    
$table.animate({height:aH});
});
$('.less').click(function(){
$table.animate({height:heightToHide});
});
```

Update: added a perfectly working fiddle: [check that out here](http://jsfiddle.net/vickysk/M2X4V/)

Answer (score 2):

`slideDown()` need the dimensions to be given explicitly so it is jerking at the end.

In your case use `show()` and `hide()` functionality, this avoid jerky

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Sht/1/)

Comment: i want some effects so i cannot use show or hide please look at the question i have mentioned there

Answer (score 0):

This is a layout job. Set up a CSS class as follow:

```
.height-30
{
  min-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

and apply it to your cells. With the implicit sizes it's often the case when the initial layout gets rejigged.

Comment: Is it the same across FF & Chrome? In FF re-flow/repaint isn't optimized at all and is way over-reactive. Let me have a closer look. Do you have any particual reason to use TBODY and THEAD - it goes against many 'good practice' docs, including google's one.

Comment: So, you are not happy with $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').slideDown(0); - you need the animation?

Comment: yeah.. a smooth animation of slide down is required.. but it should not be jerky